# SQL Query - Group consecutive items based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have no idea what to name this question.  Please forgive the title if it does not fit the question.  I have data of production and unscheduled maintenance events, ordered by Equipment and then Moment.  See below for table (see at the bottom of the question for text version):

[image]

The data should be grouped according to the indicated colors, with the Duration column being summed.  See below for the result. Basically the unscheduled maintenance hours should be summed with the production hours, until a new unscheduled maintenance event appears (thus the grouping).

I have been able to get something going by using a very complicated RANK() and join procedure, however it is very slow taking an hour to complete 500 000 records.  I need something that will work in under 5 minutes.  Note that I cannot use lead or lag function as the server that needs to execute the query is using an older version of SQL (SQL Server 2008)

Results should like this this:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

A table create statement with a lot of data can be downloaded here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xKLs3osIfcVGRCVGJMQnBYWXc/view?usp=sharing

StartDate = Moment

Ignore EndDate column

```
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| Moment              | Duration  | Equipment | DowntimeType            |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-14 08:34:03 | 2.734444  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-14 11:39:26 | 0.015833  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-14 11:41:23 | 0.4925    | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-14 12:10:56 | 0.679444  | DT46      | Unscheduled Maintenance |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-14 12:51:42 | 0.628888  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-14 15:23:48 | 0.650833  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-14 16:05:19 | 3.341111  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-14 19:44:01 | 7.292777  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-15 03:18:15 | 5.954722  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-15 09:50:54 | 3.899722  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-15 19:33:11 | 1.760277  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-15 21:18:48 | 0.637222  | DT46      | Unscheduled Maintenance |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-15 21:57:02 | 3.109722  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-16 01:14:15 | 4.128611  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-16 18:33:01 | 0.004166  | DT46      | Unscheduled Maintenance |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-16 19:19:38 | 2.580833  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-17 01:23:56 | 0.111388  | DT46      | Unscheduled Maintenance |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-17 01:30:37 | 0.293333  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-17 01:48:13 | 0.99      | DT46      | Unscheduled Maintenance |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-17 03:26:10 | 3.805833  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2014-07-17 07:14:49 | 1.435833  | DT46      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-28 01:18:43 | 1.283611  | DT63      | Unscheduled Maintenance |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-28 02:47:50 | 0.224166  | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-28 03:17:09 | 7.085277  | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-28 11:12:14 | 2.519722  | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-28 18:36:54 | 3.239166  | DT63      | Unscheduled Maintenance |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-29 03:20:04 | 1.735833  | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-29 05:07:52 | 8.631944  | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-29 23:53:44 | 6.074444  | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-11-30 23:04:51 | 14.720555 | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-12-02 01:06:50 | 0.001111  | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
| 2015-12-02 01:07:28 | 4.540277  | DT63      | Production              |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Can we see what code you have tried?

Comment: A question of this complexity would almost certainly require some testing.  As a courtesy to us, I think you should at least provide the create table statement, or better yet a demo.

Comment: What is your sql server version. Can you use running sum  (sum() with over())?

Comment: I have added a link to sql table create statement with table, as well as sql version

Comment: I can't copy your Google Doc.  Create a Rextester demo: http://www.rextester.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this grouping

```
select min(Moment), Equipment, sum(duration)
from (
  select *,
    case DowntimeType when 'Unscheduled Maintenance' 
      then row_number() over(partition by Equipment, DowntimeType order by Moment) 
      else row_number() over(partition by Equipment order by Moment) - row_number() over(partition by Equipment, DowntimeType order by Moment) end r
   from myTable
) t
where r > 0 -- must start with 'Unscheduled Maintenance' 
group by Equipment, r
order by Equipment, r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT q1.moment, q1.equipment, sum(q.duration)+q1.duration
  FROM 
        (Select moment, equipment, duration, 
                rownumber() over partition (order by moment asc) rn
          from yourtable
         where downtimetype = 'Unschedule Maintenance') q1, 
         ( Select moment, 
            rownumber() over partition (order by moment asc) rn
              from yourtable
             where downtimetype = 'Unschedule Maintenance') as q2,
             yourtable q
where q2.rn =q1.rn+1
 AND q.moment > q1.moment
 AND q.moment < q2.moment
 AND q.downtimetype ='Production'
 AND q.equipment =q1.equipment
Group by q1.moment, q1.equipment

UNION ALL
-- This is because I couldnt get the last group
Select q1.maxmoment, q.equipment, 
        sum(q.duration)+q1.duration
  FROM (SELECT * from yourtable 
         where downtimetype = 'Unschedule Maintenance' 
           and moment = (SELECT max(moment) maxmoment
                           from yourtable 


    where downtimetype = 'Unschedule Maintenance' ) )q1,
            yourtable q
     WHERE q.downtimetype ='Production'
       AND q.equipment =q1.equipment
       AND q.moment > maxmoment
group by q.moment, q.equipment
```

Am trying to

1) Assign sequential numbers for "Unschedule Maintenance".

2) Find the "production" values between two "Unschedule Maintenance" values. By having the same subquery for upper and lower limit

3) SUM the duration and group by the upper limit's (q1) moment.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
select min(StartDate) 'Moment',min(Equipment) 'Equipment',sum(Duration) 'Total Duration' from mytable a
cross apply (select top 1 b.StartDate from mytable b where b.StartDate>a.StartDate and b.[DowntimeType]='Unscheduled Maintenance' order by StartDate asc) sq1(nextMaintenance)
group by nextMaintenance
order by min(StartDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'm sure your query works, however I was not able to run it to completion as it took too long to execute